# query eloquent in controller null result, why?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

```
$rooms3 = Room::join("notifications", "notifications.room_id", "rooms.id")
            ->where('rooms.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->join("watt_histories", "watt_histories.notification_id", "notifications.id")
            ->where('notifications.id', 'watt_histories.notification_id')
            ->latest('watt_histories.created_at')
            ->first();
```

If the query runs well, the return given is not null

Comment: did you debug the sql using `dd($room3->toSql());` before using `first()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `->where('notifications.id', 'watt_histories.notification_id')`. Two reasons:

1. This condition is already handled by the join you specified.
2. The `where()` method is used to compare a column to a provided value. In this case, you're comparing the column `notifications.id` to the literal string of `"watt_histories.notification_id"`, which is why you're not getting any results. To compare two columns, use the `whereColumn()` method. However, as mentioned in 1 above, this condition isn't needed since it's already specified in the join.

```
$rooms3 = Room::join("notifications", "notifications.room_id", "rooms.id")
    ->where('rooms.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->join("watt_histories", "watt_histories.notification_id", "notifications.id")
    ->latest('watt_histories.created_at')
    ->first();
```